# Путь до картинки bitrix sql

Tags: sql, битрикс

Как в Bitrix с помощью SQL можно менять картинку товара на первью или в материале?

Все записи товаров находятся в таблице `b_iblock_element`. В ней есть папки столбцы `priview_picture` и `detail_picture` проблема в том что в них совсем не пути или ссылки а просто численный значения не понятно как связанные с финальной папкой в которой лежат изображения.

Например цифре 2 в `detail_picture` соответствует путь /upload/iblock/852/8528fffbee0d8eb38ba44856ea8d222b.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в таблице `b_file` записи с изображениями
есть айдишники и их пути.

Изменить автоматическую генерацию имен файлов и сохранять оригинальные названия можно в настройках главного модуля "Сохранять исходные имена загружаемых файлов".

Answer (score 4):

Очень редко в битриксе возникает необходимость обращаться напрямую к БД.
Чтобы получить список элементом детальными изображениями можно воспользоваться следующей конструкцией:

```
<?
$rsIBlockElementList = CIBlockElement::GetList(
            array("left_margin" => "asc"), array("ACTIVE" => "Y")
);

while ($arElement = $rsIBlockElementList->GetNext()) {
$arElement["DETAIL_PICTURE"] = (0 < $arElement["DETAIL_PICTURE"] ? CFile::GetFileArray($arElement["DETAIL_PICTURE"]) : false);
?>
    <h1><?=$arElement["NAME"]?></h1>
    <img src="<?=$arElement["DETAIL_PICTURE"]["SRC"]?>"/>
<?
}
?>
```